# Switch from single to double column in the same page

Tags: two-column

I need to write a text just in this format

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}.
```

But I need to switch between single column and double column several times in the same page, without jumping to a new page every time I switch the format. Is this possible without using any package like  `\usepackage{multicol}` ?

Comment: why don't you want to use multicol (which is designed to do exactly that)

Comment: Could you mock up an example of the possible page layout you want?

Comment: there is no reason not to use `multicol.st` it has the same status as `article.cls` a file in the core latex distribution, you have to input some macro files or you can not typeset anything in latex.

Answer (score 28):

You should look into using the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and its `multicols` environment. For instance, the following code produces a page that starts in single-column mode, switches to two-column mode, and finally switches back to single-column mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
% switch to two-column layout
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}
% switch back to single-column layout
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this not mess up marginnotes?

Comment: @mathtick - Not sure what you're driving at. For a document to produce meaningful twocolumn output, the margins have to be rather slim. Hence I see no reason to worry about a lack of space for margin notes to begin with.

Comment: This works, but creates another problem, that is, `multicol` doesn't work with floats.