# Create "Section Break" in Latex as in Word

Tags: multicol, lscape

I tried to use lscape and multicol as described in "[How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode#354)" and in "[Switch from single to double column in the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275264/switch-from-single-to-double-column-in-the-same-page)" but I never get the header and footer be in such a nice format as they are in the Word document (see Pictures).
Does anyone know a "trick" how to handle such a case?

[image: Word, Page 1]
[image: Word, Page 2]
[image: Word, Page 3]

Comment: (pdf)lscape is designed to rotate the body of the page while keeping the head and foot in the usual landscape orientation. If you want the head and foot to also rotate then a similar code could probably be devised but I'm not aware of an existing packaged solution.