# Change multiple times the number of columns in the same page, without page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

I would like to change the number of columns of a page just like the following:

2 columns --> no columns --> 3 columns.

But multicol inserts a page-break whenever I use its environment.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc

\end{multicols*}

abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc

\begin{multicols*}{3}

abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275264/switch-from-single-to-double-column-in-the-same-page . Try to come up with a better MWE: Your text consists of a single word per `multicol` environment, there is nothing to break or balance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment; when making the MWE I realized that multicol indeed worked, it was not doing so because I was using the asterisk version of it, which breaks the page (I couldn't remember even the reason why I was using the *). I'll post the MWE as the answer, in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using the "\begin{multicols}{} ... \end{multicols}" (the asterisk version breaks the page).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \section{Two columns}
    \lipsum[1-1]
\end{multicols}

\section{No column}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \path[thick,fill=red!80] (1.7,1)--(1.7,-1)--(5,0)--cycle;
    \path[thick,fill=blue!80] (1.7,1)--(1.7,-1)--(-0.2,0)--cycle;
    \draw[ultra thick] (-0.2,0)--(1.7,1)--(5,0)--(1.7,-1)--cycle;
    \draw[ultra thick] (1.7,1)--(1.7,-1);
    \node[label={center:\Huge{N}}] at (2.5,0) {};
    \node[label={center:\Huge{S}}] at (0.9,0) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \section{Two columns}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]